# How many unit paths are there in R3

Tags: plane-geometry

How many unit paths are there in $\Bbb R^3$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(n,n,n)$ that never pass below the plane $y=x$?  This means that for every point $(a,b,c)$ on the path we have $a\le b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Do you know how to do it in $\Bbb R^2$?  See the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  Then pick $n$ places of the path of $3n$ to put steps in the third axis.  Why does this work?

Comment: I think that for R2 you would do 2n choose n to get the total number off paths and then do 2n choose n-1 to get the number of paths that go below and subtract them.

Comment: I was asking why my approach works to move from 2D to 3D